# PHP Singleton Return NULL if use App::init();

Tags: php, dependency-injection, singleton

I practicing design pattern (Singleton And dependency injection ) in php ,
the issue is when i set another index file in run(){} to set and test the routes
so if create another instance from Applaction class in new index file:

- if i use Applaction::init() as function will return NULL ;
- but if i use  Applaction::$init; .. will works fine !!!

```
<?php 
namespace System;
class Applaction{


 public static $init = null; //instance    
 
 public Array $container = [];

 private function __construct(File $file)
{
        static::$init = $this;

        $this->share('files', $file); 

        $this->setClasses();

        $this->loadFunctions();
}

//create class instance    
public static function init($file = null){
    if(is_null(static::$init)){
        static::$init = new static($file);
        return static::$init;
    }
}

public function run(){
    $this->session->start();

    //use App/index.php File for test 
    $this->files->getFiles('App/index.php');

    $this->request->setUrl();

    list($controller, $method, $args) = $this->route->getProperRoute(); 

    $this->load->controller($controller);
}
```

//Works Fine with this

```
<?php 
 //App\index.php

 use System\Applaction;

 $app =  Applaction::$init; // $init ?!

$app->route->add('/', 'Home');
```

here return NULL

```
<?php 

 //App\index.php

 use System\Applaction;

 $app =  Applaction::init(); // method init()

$app->route->add('/', 'Home');
```

Comment: A property is not a method. Singleton is an anti-pattern! Do not use, when using DI.

Comment: (FYI, the English word that you most likely _meant_, is spelled `Application`.)

Comment: If you were to use a singleton in this manner it would look more like [this](https://3v4l.org/WqG2N). Don’t be cheap on variable names, either. You had one called `init` with a comment saying that it was an instance, just call it the instance, no comment needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone ...

update :

```
class Application{


 public static $instance = null;   
 
 private Array $container = [];

 private function __construct($file = null)
{
        //self::$instance = $this;

        $this->share('files', $file); 

        $this->setClasses();

        $this->loadFunctions();
}

public static function getInstance($file = null){
    if(is_null(self::$instance)){
        self::$instance = new static($file);
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

public function run(){
    $this->session->start();

    $this->files->getFiles('App/index.php');

    $this->request->setUrl();

    list($controller, $method, $args) = $this->route->getProperRoute(); 

    $this->load->action($controller, $method, $args);
}
```